# Redirect wildcard multi-urls to homepage

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanted to redirect unknown urls to my homepage using PHP or htaccess. Found one but seems it was for one wildcard match only. I would like to know if using conditional tag or switch will help me redirect the unknown urls matching their specific wordings to homepage.

Here's the idea.

```
if ("unknown url 1" is equal to "wildcard url condition") :
 - location redirect to "domain.com"
elseif ("unknown url 2" is equal to "wildcard url condition") :
 - location redirect to "domain.com"
endif;
```

Although, if there's another option and easy to redirect using htaccess hope someone can help me how to write it.

Reason why I would like to use this if possible, is to reduce amount of high volume registering 404 Not Found to our Webmaster Tools.

**Update**

Here's another idea that i am working on.

```
// List all keywords for wildcard match
$patterns = array( 'dev', 'new', 'php', 'html' );
$patterns_flattened = implode(' ', $patterns);

// Get 404 Not Found URL
$404_notfound = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Match the define keywords and 404 Not Found
if ( preg_match('/'. $patterns_flattened .'/', $404_notfound) ) :
  header("Location: http://www.domain.com");
endif;
```

Though I'm getting error here... Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think i found an alternative solution.

```
$wildcards['keywords'] = array('dev', 'new', 'php', 'html');
$string = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$max = array(null, 0);
foreach($wildcards as $k => $v) {
  $replaced = str_replace($v, '##########', $string);
  if (preg_match_all('/##########/i', $replaced, $matches)) {
      header('Location: http://www.domain.com/');
      exit;
  }
}
```